# Pspell default dictionary

Tags: php

When I use pspell_check (http://php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-check.php), what dictionary is used? Where can I find the dictionary file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the **aspell library** to use the **pspell*** functions.The dictionaries are in http://aspell.net/

The files are compiled with PHP,so find your version in your system.